# Can you add emulsifying salts when making mozzarella?

Tags: cheese, cheese-making, mozzarella

Pretty much what the title says, I want to improve the stability of melted mozzarella for a dish I want to make. Haven't made mozzarella before, but if I make it at home, is there a stage I could add sodium citrate (or sodium phosphate) like is done to make American cheese gooey like it is?

Answer (score 1):

Well as such you can't add emulsifying salt in the preparation of natural mozzarella cheese. If you want to prepare processed mozzarella cheese then you can add emulsifying salts for better improvement of emulsification properties and protein solubilization, it helps in reducing free fat leakage. the stability of melted mozzarella cheese depends upon many factors associated with manufacturing steps i.e. cooking temperature, scalding time, the acidity of whey drainage etc... so you have to take care about each and every aspect of manufacturing step to make it more stable in their melted form.

Comment: The cheap American cheese brands got sloppy with this about a decade ago. Haven't bought it since. It's no good on pizza, and a disaster in Rigatoni. There at least I can substitute our fake American Parmesan.